# Unbounded norm convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-lattices

I study on unbounded norm convergence in Banach lattice. I have to find an example.Is there any example of unbounded norm convergence but not norm convergence in Banach lattice?

Answer (score 0):

The standard basis of $l_1$ is un-converges to $0$ but not norm converges.